# Returning lines containing two or more keywords

Tags: python, set, intersection

I want to iterate through a number of lines (containing text) and return only those lines that contain two or more of the words in a list of keywords.

I have been trying with making the wordlist and keywordlist into sets to use the intersect function, like:

```
if len(set(line).intersection(set(keywords))) >1:
    print line
```

Also tried with various types of nested loops like

```
if word in line
```

But no success yet.

Comment: Are you splitting the line into its various words? The `set` of a string is just a `set` containing each character: e.g. `set("abc") = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])`.

Comment: Also you really only want to convert the keywords to a set once, before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and split the line on whitespace before you convert it into a set:

```
if len(set(line.split()).intersection(set(keywords))) > 1:
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> keywords = ['if', 'def', 'class']
>>> line = 'if def word'
>>> len(set(line).intersection(set(keywords))) > 1
False
>>> len(set(line.split()).intersection(set(keywords))) > 1
True
>>>
```

Without this change, you will get a set of characters instead of a set of words:

```
>>> line = 'if def word'
>>> set(line)
{' ', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'r', 'w'}
>>> set(line.split())
{'word', 'if', 'def'}
>>>
```

Comment: I am opening an 'infile' and a 'keywords' file from *.txt. The infile has a sentence containing both "and" and "or". The keywords file consists of the words "and" and "or". If I do: `for line in infile:` and then: `if len(set(line.split()).intersection(set(keywords))) > 1: print line`, it prints nothing, even though the line in the infile matches two of the keywords. What am I missing?

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly, but I think I know the problem.  If `keywords` is a file object, then placing it in `set` will not strip the newline at the end of each line.  You need to do: `set(line.strip() for line in keywords)`.

Comment: Hmm. `if len(set(line.split()).intersection(set(line.strip() for line in keywords))) > 1:`still does not solve it.

Comment: My solution above is for if there is one keyword per line.  If all keywords are on one line however and separated by whitespace, then you need to do: `set(keywords.read().split())`.  If this does not work, then I would recommend asking a new question.  You will receive the best help that way.  Also, if you are looking for Python keywords, you should use [`keyword.kwlist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist).